# Can a page tab post to a user's wall?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a Facebook application used as a tab in a fan page, that displays different information depending on whether tha user is a fan of that page or not.

Now I've been asked to have it post a message to a user's wall if they perform certain action (follow a link or whatever), and so far I haven't found a way to do that. All the documentation I have found refers to stand alone apps, and I've even seen it suggested (in the FB forums) that you can't get the auth token from an app.

So, i still think it can be done, but how?

Comment: Can you use server-side script? JS SDK?

Comment: Looks like not in the tab itself, but the app can also have a website with the sdk. i'm checking that out.

Answer (score 0):

If a user has authorized your app, you can post to her wall using the PHP SDK. See the PHP SDK [api documentation](https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) for examples.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely. If you have an App ID and secret, you can run the example on that page, which is a complete example that posts to the logged-in user's wall.

Comment: Thing is regular applications, connected websites and tab applications work differently, have access to different information and so. I ended up redirecting users to a website outside of the tab, where i can get permissions and post to the user's wall (in the tab you can't see the user's info or get permissions)

Answer (score 0):

All apps have to be iframe apps now, so loading the JS sdk should be fine.

You have to **get permissions first** ->

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin

Then you can post using php with what Dhiren said, or, **post with the fb.api function with JS** ->
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Let me know if you need an example script.

Cheers

Comment: IN the end I'm using the php sdk from a website (that is the same app) and redirecting. So far it works like it should.

Comment: Cool. What function is it that you use in the php sdk?

Comment: I ended up making something very similar to http://nocturnsoft.com/devblog/?p=1745